# Displaying Hashmap data using datatable in jsp

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a hashmap and I am displaying the map data in a table with custom pagination. 
How can I change it such that jQuery data-table can be used to display it.
How do I iterate over the hashmap in jsp and display it in datatable. 
I am not using any AJAX call, but fetching data through normal action class.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem in using the forEach construct

users items and var attributes of the for each tag.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm